# Azure devops - ignore certain files saved to git when comparing two branches

Tags: git, azure-devops

Hi we've got Azure Devops as our Git.

We load the config files in our various branches up to git, so if we ever lose the local copies we have everything we need to restore a working version.  Obviously the config for release (Master) is different from Dev (different databases, often different versions of software as we test updates etc.).

Is there any way to include files in a git/commit, but then selectively ignore them when comparing branches, so we can compare all the code differences between the branches without wading through the config differences etc?

Comment: Tried https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere?

Comment: Do you mean the Branch compare feature in `Azure Repos ->  Branches`?

Comment: Sort of, except unfortunately the branch compare also references all the .less, css, config etc. files, and I'm not interested in those.  I'm happy to set up a list of 'ignore in compare' files but I still need them loaded into the git, so they cant go into the 'proper'.gitignore file